# Weibels Proof that $H^{2}$ classifies extensions

Tags: lie-algebras

I'm trying to understand Weibel's proof that $H^{2}$ classifies extensions of Lie algebras in section 7.6 of Homological algebra. I understand most of the proof until the last section when he shows that the classifying map he has constructed from $\text{Ext}^{1}(g, M) $ to $H^{2}(g, M)$ is injective.

I am not going to write out the full proof, because it is a little bit complicated, but there is one specific part I do not understand.

Weibel defines a $g$-module homomorphism:

$$\tau: f \to e_{1}$$
$$x \mapsto \tau_{1}(x) + D(x) $$

Where $f$ is a free $g$-module, $e_{1}$ is a $g$-module, $ \tau_{1}$ is a $g$-module homomorphism (from $f$ to $e_{1}$), and $D$ is a derivation.

He then argues that $\tau$ is a $g$-module homomorphism as follows:

\begin{align}
\tau([x, y]) &= \tau_{1}([x, y]) + D([x, y]) \\
&= [\tau_{1}(x), \tau_{1}(y)] +x(Dy) - y(Dx) \\
&= [\tau_{1}(x) + Dx, \tau_{1}(y) +Dy] \\
&= [\tau(x), \tau(y)]
\end{align}

I do not understand why this is true. Why is it the case that:$$ [\tau_{1}(x), \tau_{1}(y)] +x(Dy) - y(Dx) = [\tau_{1}(x) + Dx, \tau_{1}(y) +Dy] ~\text{?}$$

Is this a general fact that holds for any g-module homomorphism $\tau_{1}$ and for any derivation $D$?

Thanks for your help.